# z-index not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, z-index

I am currently working with Leaflet and Mapbox to create a custom map. All has been working fine until I started to work on the popups.

My situation: I have a custom navigation/control panel that will be used but it needs to be **behind** any open popups (which it currently is not).

I have prepared a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q502rttq/) and this screenshot

[image]

Part of my CSS is

```
#map-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.leaflet-popup-pane, .leaflet-popup {
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

The default leaflet classes have `z-index` of 7 (I think), I just overwrote it to be 100% sure. When inspecting the code in browser (FF/Chrome), I see that the z-index is set properly and no other element in the `.leaflet-popup` has any `z-index` set.

I have read that negative `z-index` may solve this, but as I am working with multiple elements I'd really much like a less "hacky" solution - if there is one. (JavaScript solutions are welcome as well, hence the tag)

As I can see from the code inspection, Leaflet sets some attributes to `.leaflet-popup` which in terms of position are: `transform: translate3d(..)`, `bottom` and `left`.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I can put the `#map-nav` inside `#map-content` and it still won't work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q502rttq/6/). However, when I try to imitate this without alle the map stuff, [it does work](http://jsfiddle.net/vnvumsmh/).

Comment: z-index is working only if `position` is set explicitly. Is it in this case?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot I did not want to bloat the question any more but have added the additional information now

Comment: I see your problem. It doesn't work because the elements are in different parent. If you give`z-index:5;` to `#map-content`. You understand me.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since a leaflet popup is content of your `<div id="map-content"></div>` and the z-index of map-content is below the map-nav div.

Comment: @kingkero This can't be done. Read this to understand why: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: @alirezasafian please see my edit. It is no problem to put the navigation inside `#map-content`

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery's UI framework and the class found here? https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/stacking-elements/

I'm not sure if they're compatible. Just an idea.

Comment: You should add it inside `.leaflet-popup-pane` to work.

Comment: You can achieve your desire situation by jquery. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/q502rttq/7/) to understand it better. Feel free to ask any question. I'll answer it as soon as possible.

Comment: @alirezasafian No hurry here ;) Thanks for that, sadly it doesn't position the navigation properly when I try it ((looks like this)[http://i.imgur.com/JslNDfQ.jpg]). But to be honest, I think hiding the navigation (without creating another one) for small screens shouldn't be too much of a problem

Comment: @kingkero I'm sorry to replay latr. I just wanted to give you and others some ideas to what the problem is and solve it fast.

Comment: @canon don't afraid I didn't say "I solve the problem"

Comment: @canon Thank you very much again for your expertise on this topic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `#map-nav` exists in an entirely different stacking context than the marker and its popup.

[image]

The way you have it set up right now, the entire map is behind `#map-nav`. So, changing the z-index on either `#map-nav` or the `.leaflet-popup-pane` won't really help.

> **Disclaimer**: This is a terrible, terrible hack. If you look into Leaflet's documentation and find a way to add your own widgets, I'd highly recommend doing *that* instead of *this*.

That said, I have something which sort of works ([your mileage may vary](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)):

1. Move `#map-nav` into `.leaflet-map-pane`
2. Create a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and observe changes to the attributes of `.leaflet-map-pane`.
3. Whenever the `style` attribute of `.leaflet-map-pane` changes, grab its `style.transform` property and extract the x and y values. Invert those values and apply them to `#map-nav`.

```js
var map = L.map('map-content', {
  zoomControl: false
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'rauschundrausch.cih3gisks00r8rlly0ob5s2me',
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmF1c2NodW5kcmF1c2NoIiwiYSI6ImNpaTYyeW14MTAwNml2eW0zcmR6aHIzdDcifQ.6T8nzYq49rFnvcqk6lgYPg'
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("this is a<br>large<br>popup<br>in<br>terms of height");

var mapNav = document.getElementById("map-nav");

var mapPane = document.querySelector(".leaflet-map-pane");

var rxTranslate = /translate(?:3d)?\(([^\)]+)\)/i;

mapPane.appendChild(mapNav);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if (mutations.some(m => m.attributeName === "style")) {
    // apply an inverse transform
    mapNav.style.transform = "translate(" + mapPane
      .style
      .transform
      .match(rxTranslate)[1]
      .split(",")
      .slice(0, 2) /* extract only x and y; discard z */
      .map(n => parseFloat(n) * -1 + "px") /* invert values */ + ")";
  }
});

observer.observe(mapPane, {
  attributes: true
});
```

```css
#map {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#map-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f00;
}
#map-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.leaflet-popup-pane {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map">
  <div id="map-content">
    <div id="map-nav"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This may lag on some clients while dragging. You could use a timeout to defer the update but that would mean the nav menu would move around until you stop dragging.

Comment: Beat me to it. It may sound hacky, but it's the only way as far as I can tell. Nice solution.